# Ruby : stack level too deep (SystemStackError)

Tags: ruby, algorithm, stack

I try to solve this problem http://www.nattee.net/~dae/algo/prob/hw03b_tiling/problem.pdf

So I using divide and conquer method to solve it but when I execute my program I get

```
tile.rb:7: stack level too deep (SystemStackError)
```

And this is my code

```
def tile (x, y, bx, by, ex, ey)
    mx = (bx+ex)/2
    my = (by+ey)/2

    if (by<=y && y<=my)
        if (bx<=x && x<=mx) # top-left
            puts "0 #{mx} #{my}"
        elsif (mx+1<=x && x<=ex) # top-right
            puts "1 #{mx} #{my}"
        end
    elsif (my+1<=y && y<=ey)
        if (bx<=x && x<=mx) # bottom-left
            puts "2 #{mx} #{my}"
        elsif (mx+1<=x && x<=ex) # bottom-right
            puts "3 #{mx} #{my}"
        end
    end

    tile(x,y,bx,by,mx,my) #top-left
    tile(x,y,mx+1,by,ey,my) #top-right
    tile(x,y,bx,my+1,mx+1,ey)   #bottom-left
    tile(x,y,mx+1,my+1,ex,ey) #bottom-right

    if ex-bx == 2 && ey-by == 2 then return end
end

temp = []
gets.chomp.strip.split(" ").each do |item|
temp << item.to_i
end

L = temp[0]
x = temp[1]
y = temp[2]

tile(x,y,0,0,L-1,L-1)
```

I can't find the cause.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no way out of your recursion - for every call to `tile`, it will make 4 more calls to `tile`.    Recursion always needs a "relief valve" way out *before* the recursion call.   Try moving your `return` up before the `tile` calls.

The return statement could stand to be written in more idiomatic ruby.

Try:

```
return if (ex-bx == 2 && ey-by == 2)
```

Comment: If that syntax were illegal, it would raise a `SyntaxError` during parsing and never even start executing in the first place.

Comment: quite right, I missed the `then`.   nevertheless, my suggestion is more idiomatic ruby.